# Why i am getting 400 Bad Request?

Tags: wcf, rest

My Code:

```
[DataContract(Namespace="http://yournamespace.com")
public class MyContract
{
   [DataMember(Order=1)]
   public string MyData1 { get(); set{};}

   [DataMember(order=2)]
   public string MyData2 { get(); set{};}

}


[WebInvoke(method="POST")]
public string DoSomethingFromPost(MyContract postedData)
{
   String s="Success";
   return s;
}
```

Request Input:

```
<MyContract xmlns="http://yournamespace.com">
<MyData1>value</MyData1>
<MyData2>value</MyData2>
</MyContract>
```

While Testing it in Rest Client i am getting 400 Bad Request.
Please tell me how to test the post method in Rest Client.why i am getting 400 bad request.

Please tell me.........

Answer (score 1):

You need to have your request as shown below for it to work:

```
<MyContract xmlns="http://yournamespace.com" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<MyData1>value</MyData1>
<MyData2>value</MyData2>
</MyContract>
```

When you get HTTP status code 400 then you can enable tracing on your service to know the exact reason for the bad request. To enable tracing follow this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx)